# Application redirectling to default page of JBoss EAP 7.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, redhat, jboss-eap-7

I am moving my Java EE application to JBoss EAP 7 from JBoss EAP 6.4.7. On hitting the application login page, I am getting the page as per the below highlighted text. What change do I need to make in my standalone to redirect to the application login page.

**Welcome to JBoss EAP 7
Your Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform is running.
Administration Console | Documentation | Online User Groups 
To replace this page simply deploy your own war with / as its context path.
To disable it, remove the "welcome-content" handler for location / in the undertow subsystem.**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.1">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld" />
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" />
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation" />
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io" />
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller" />
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager" />
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow" />
        <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-subsystem" />
    </extensions>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.allowMultipleLastResources"
            value="true" />
        <property name="Memcached.IP" value="192.168.0.237" />
        <property name="Memcached.Port" value="11211" />
        <property name="Redis.IP" value="10.225.241.133" />
        <property name="Redis.Port" value="6379" />
        <property name="Redis.Password" value="altredispasswordsohum" />
        <property name="Redis.Client.PoolSize" value="128" />
        <property name="Redis.Database.Id" value="15" />
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT"
            value="10000" />
        <property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="9000" />
    </system-properties>


    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true" />
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"
                        skip-group-loading="true" />
                    <properties path="application-users.properties"
                        relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties"
                        relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter" />
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter"
                    path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir" />
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file" />
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm"
                http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket-binding http="management-http" />
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local" />
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO" />
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN" />
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE"
                autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN" />
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log" />
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
                <append value="true" />
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN" />
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG" />
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN" />
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO" />
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE" />
                    <handler name="FILE" />
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n" />
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n" />
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:1.0">
            <default-job-repository name="in-memory" />
            <default-thread-pool name="batch" />
            <job-repository name="in-memory">
                <in-memory />
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool name="batch">
                <max-threads count="10" />
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds" />
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
                    pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/Database"
                    pool-name="Database" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"
                    use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://192.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=Database</connection-url>
                    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>UserName</user-name>
                        <password>Password</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
                        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments"
                relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"
                runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default"
                        jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default"
                        use-transaction-setup-provider="true" />
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default"
                        jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"
                        context-service="default" />
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default"
                        jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default"
                        context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000"
                        keepalive-time="5000" />
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service
                        name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default"
                        context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000"
                        keepalive-time="3000" />
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default"
                datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
                managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default"
                managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default"
                managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool" />
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"
                    passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple" />
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000" />
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool"
                        derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5"
                        instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" />
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool"
                        derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5"
                        instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" />
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" />
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan"
                    aliases="passivating clustered" />
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan"
                    cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000" />
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default" />
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default"
                default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data"
                        relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir" />
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector"
                thread-pool-name="default" />
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10" />
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds" />
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other" />
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access
                value="true" />
            <log-system-exceptions value="true" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
            <worker name="default" />
            <buffer-pool name="default" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
            <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default"
                module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
                <local-cache name="default">
                    <transaction mode="BATCH" />
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation"
                module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH" />
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false" />
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH" />
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false" />
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb"
                default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH" />
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false" />
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ" />
                    <transaction mode="BATCH" />
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false" />
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query"
                module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA" />
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000" />
                    <expiration max-idle="100000" />
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000" />
                    <expiration max-idle="100000" />
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps" />
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:4.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true"
                fail-on-warn="false" />
            <bean-validation enabled="true" />
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50" />
                    <queue-length count="50" />
                    <max-threads count="50" />
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds" />
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50" />
                    <queue-length count="50" />
                    <max-threads count="50" />
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds" />
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model />
            <expose-expression-model />
            <remoting-connector />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource=""
                default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp" />
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
            <endpoint />
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector"
                connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
            <deployment-permissions>
                <maximum-set>
                    <permission class="java.security.AllPermission" />
                </maximum-set>
            </deployment-permissions>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required" />
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required" />
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication-jaspi>
                        <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                            <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional" />
                        </login-module-stack>
                        <auth-module code="Dummy" />
                    </authentication-jaspi>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:3.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid />
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment"
                status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
            <buffer-cache name="default" />
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"
                    redirect-socket="https" />
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content" />
                    <filter-ref name="server-header" />
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header" />
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config />
                <websockets />
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content" />
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server"
                    header-value="JBoss-EAP/7" />
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header"
                    header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1" />
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config" />
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers"
                    protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler"
                        class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler" />
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:3.0" />
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}" />
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}" />
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets"
        default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management"
            port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}" />
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management"
            port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}" />
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}" />
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}" />
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}" />
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712" />
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713" />
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25" />
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the welcome page said :

> To replace this page simply deploy your own war with / as its context
>   path.

To deploy an application to the root context ('/'), just add jboss-web.xml with the bellow values to the WEB-INF folder of your WAR :

```
 <jboss-web>
   <context-root></context-root>
 </jboss-web>
```

Another option is naming the application `ROOT.war`

To disable "welcome-content" handler, remove line 434 of you `standalone.xml` :

```
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content" />
```